# How can I get item Ids without querying entire items?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get a list of item ids with the code below, not a list of items, but I am not getting any Ids although the response message has Count set to the expected number of items. Could you please let me know if it is possible to get item ids only without item contents and how? Thanks.

```
string query = "select r.Id from root r where r.itemType = @itemType";
QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(query);
queryDefinition.WithParameter("@itemType", ItemType.Banana);

using (var feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(queryDefinition))
{
while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
using (ResponseMessage responseMessage = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
{
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseMessage.Content))
{
using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
JObject content = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<JObject>(jsonTextReader);
if (content.ContainsKey("Documents"))
{
foreach (var doc in content["Documents"])
{
// why doc is empty?
}
}
}
}
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To just get the ids back without each one being it's own document, change your query to select value(r.Id) from root r where r.itemType = @itemType

Comment: thanks Mark. I tried that but got 0 count of ids, so the above might have a syntax issue. i also tried this but the same result.

select value r.Id from root r where r.itemType = @itemType

Comment: Try your query in the Data Explorer and see if you get a result there.

Comment: i tried that in data explorer. the result was the same; 0 results and no error message shown in anywhere. the query was supported in document db sdk (2.7). please let me know if it is also supported in cosmos sdk (3.12) and if not, what would be an efficient way to get ids.

Comment: okay, i found an issue in the query. it was a case issue in "Id". it should be "id" (lower case 'i'). it works now. thanks Mark!